# Using EventWaitHandles between Windows Service and Windows Application

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a requirement to send a signal from a Windows Service to a Windows console/Forms application using Named Events. I created a common NamedEvents class library which has the implementation to create events.

The issue is that my windows service is not creating the event. If I create another Windows Forms application (in place of the windows service) to create a event then it works fine. But with Windows Service it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please advise me if I am missing something in my code

```
public static class NamedEvents
{
    public static EventWaitHandle OpenOrCreate(string name, bool  initialState, EventResetMode mode)
    {
        EventWaitHandle ewh = null;
        try
        {                
            ewh = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(name);
        }
        catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
        {                
            ewh = new EventWaitHandle(initialState, mode, name);
        }

        return ewh;
    }

    public static EventWaitHandle OpenOrWait(string name)
    {
        EventWaitHandle ewh = null;

        while (null == ewh)
        {
            try
            {
                ewh = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(name);
            }
            catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

        return ewh;
    }
}
```

Windows Service Code:

```
public void SetSignalToClient()
{
    EventWaitHandle completedA = NamedEvents.OpenOrCreate("CompletedA", false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);                     
    completedA.Set();
    completedA.Close();
}
```

Windows Forms Application:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    new Task((o) => SubscribeToAsyncEvents(),
            new System.Threading.CancellationToken()).Start(); 
}

private void SubscribeToAsyncEvents()
{            
    while (true)
    {
        EventWaitHandle completedA = NamedEvents.OpenOrWait("CompletedA");
        completedA.WaitOne();
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = "received"; });
        }
        completedA.Close();               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the [MSDN article for CreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx).  In order to use an event object across multiple Terminal Services sessions (also known as Remote Desktop sessions) you must create a global event object, which you can do by starting the name that with the prefix `Global\`, e.g., `Global\MyEventName`.

While the documentation does not mention it, to the best of my knowledge, the .NET EventWaitHandle class will pass the event name to CreateEvent unchanged.  So the same mechanism should work.

Windows Services run in session 0, and user applications run in session 1 or higher.  So for a service and a user application to communicate, they must use global objects.

Note that if the user application is not running as an administrator, the service will probably also need to explicitly set the permissions on the event object.

Comment: Thank you for your response Harry. From your suggestion, I used the Global prefix in my service while creating an event and also while open the event(from windows forms) but it still it didnt work. So followed your another suggestion to set permissions on the event object and now my service is crashing with an exception: **System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException**
For setting the permissions, I used the snippet from the link
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c9z2kt(v=vs.110).aspx ]

Comment: After Changing my service Account type from Local System to "User" it is now working as expected. It is working fine on my system, but what I am not of the circumstances of changing the service account type to User, will there be any other unknown complication when running this service in customer location?

Comment: That code snippet does the wrong thing, it sets explicit access rules for the current user (i.e., the user the service is running as).  You need to grant access to the particular user(s) that will be running the application, or to a group like Users or a generic security identity such as INTERACTIVE.  Also, that code *denies* access to signal or wait on the event, you presumably want to *allow* access for one or both.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I tried to follow your suggestions and used InteractiveSID, but it didnt work. I used the LocalSystemSid, it worked once and after then it never called the Set() at all..below is my code


var users = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null);

var rule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(users, EventWaitHandleRights.Synchronize | EventWaitHandleRights.Modify,
                                          AccessControlType.Allow);